# How to test updated signing key from Play Store

Tags: google-play, digital-signature, signature, android-app-signing, key-rotation

We recently updated our app signing key from the Play Store. We opted for a Google managed key, and to use it just for new installs (on Android 13 and above).

What I see is that the apk for an Android 13 has both keys within its lineage and the legacy key is still used to sign (so it's the same for all Android versions), and it will be replaced by the new signing key through a key rotation (feature introduced in signature v3) performed during an app update.

so the question is, how can I test my application with the updated key? Shall I install it on a device and wait for an app update? How can I obtain an apk signed with the new key so that I can perform all the required tests (deep links, integration with service providers, etc.)?

Anyone is experiencing the same issue?